# Tableau - Toggle between 2 measures by single select filter on one basic text grid

Tags: tableau-api

looking to have a basic text grid by month by product, and then have a single filter on only 2 of the measures.  For example:

```
Measures Filter
------------------
[ ] Sales      <-- only show this
[X] Quantity   <-- and this as options
[ ] Interest       (don't show in filter)
[ ] Fee            ( don't show in filter)



          JAN   |   FEB  |   MAR  |  APR  |  MAY  | etc ...
products 
ITEM1      x         x        x       x       x
ITEM2      x         x        x       x       x
ITEM3      x         x        x       x       x
```

So the user can basically toggle between Sales or Quantity, and whichever they click on will fill out the x by month.

I was able to get this to work for everything except only showing the 2 measures I want to filter for.  It only shows all measures for me in the filter and I can't figure out how to hide them.

What I did was
Drag Date to columns
Drag Product and MeasureNames to Rows

Can someone please help me on getting this correct?  Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct use case of FILTERS.  **Filters** are normally used to filter (read subset) the data (read rows).  Say for example If your dataset has 1000 rows/records and you want some report/visual/aggregation on say 500 rows (based on some criteria of course) you have to filter the data.  For selection of argument (user based) in some report/viz, etc. **Parameters** are used.

Your desired example output is also a perfect case of use of Parameters.  You may proceed as follows-

**Step-1** Create a parameter (say `parameter 1`) with values as `SALES` and `QUANTITY`.

**Step-2** Create a calculated field (say `CF1`) with the following calculation

```
CASE [parameter 1]
WHEN 'SALES` THEN [sales]
WHEN 'Quantity' then [Quantity]
END
```

*Note:  It is assumed that your field/column names in dataset are `sales` and `Quantity`*

**Step-3** Build your view (Crosstab here) with

- `months` on Columns shelf
- `products` on rows shelf
- `CF1` on text in Marks card (alternatively just double click it)
- Choose measure for aggregation of `CF1` as desired (default will be sum)

**Step-4** right click `paramter 1` and click `show parameter`. (select desired measure for aggregation in crosstab)

*VOILA* your desired view is complete.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal this worked perfectly, thanks for the detailed instructions and explanation of FILTER and PARAMETER!  I did have a random dashboard layout question I was hoping you can help with: on my dash I have a layout of several worksheets in the 1 row, 2 columns (think of a carton of eggs standing up).  At the very bottom of the dash I'd like to add a single worksheet that spans both columns, but I cant figure out how to merge the cells.  It just goes to the left half or the right half of the dashboard.  I could do floating as an option but there must be a simple way I'm missing, any idea?

Comment: Glad to have been help. Please accept the answer also as usually desired on SO.  Regarding your layout of dashboard, there is a ready to place container like you have specified.  Use that container before placing sheets on dash.

Comment: Just accepted @AnilGoyal thanks again!  Regarding layout, I don't see that option, does that mean I can't add this to the bottom of an existing dashboard, I have to completely start a new dashboard and pre-determine the layout?  I have a lot of floating filters and legends throughout my dashboard.  I figured there would be an easy way to merge two empty sections or Blank objects to create 1 section spanning the width of the dashboard.  thanks again!

Comment: There must be some option.  Let me check it. :)

Comment: thank you , let me know if you find anything, I'm struggling to find a solution for this and it seems like it should be a necessity for anyone looking to add to an existing dashboard.  I can't imagine Tableau wouldn't have something this basic, ahhhh! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is another options to add to Anil's good suggestion. You can also use [Measure Names as a filter](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-measure-names-filter/). Hide all measures apart from those you want in the filter, then put Measure Names on the filter shelf.

However, this means you can't use the hidden measures from the data source elsewhere, which can be a deal breaker. Duplicating the data source is a way around that limitation.

But if you only want to show the 2 measures and are happy with single select, then [choosing the measure by parameter](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-parameters-allow-user-selecting-measure/) is the better option, as Anil suggests.

Comment: Andy nice explanations given on your webpage.  Thanks for sharing.  Upvoted